# Converting several video files into audio with MoviePy

Tags: python, audio, video, moviepy, video-conversion

I have been trying to create a *for loop in which Python goes through all of the video files in a folder, and converts each individual video file to a new audio file*.
I know that effective code for doing it exists, but only for individual files.

**This is my code:**

```
import moviepy
import os
import moviepy.editor 
import tempfile

pathdir = "path/to/dir"

for filename in os.listdir(pathdir):
    filename.endswith(".mkv")
    print(filename)
        
    video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(filename)
    audio = video.audio
    audio.write_audiofile(filename + ".wav")
    
else:
    print("Finished conversion")
```

And this is what comes up - notice the correct filename is printed, thus identified.

```
runfile('path/to/dir/convert video to audio script.py', wdir='path/to/dir/')
fg_av_ger_seg0.mkv
Traceback (most recent call last):

OSError: MoviePy error: the file fg_av_ger_seg0.mkv could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

For your information, here is the code it is based on, which works fine but only for a single file:

```
import moviepy.editor

video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip('sample.mp4')
audio = video.audio
audio.write_audiofile('audio.mp3')
```

*Thank you for your help. I am a beginner, so I apologies in advance if the error is basic!* :)

Comment: What is `path/to/dir`? Is it a real path, or are you hiding the real path? Why are you using `runfile`? Try debugging your code using an IDE like PyCharm or Spyder.

Comment: Hello, I was hiden the real path! I thought it wouldn't be essential, maybe I'm wrong haha? The second set of information are the returned errors! everything from runfile to Please check. I am actually using Spyder!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a path issue...

- The line `filename.endswith(".mkv")` supposed to be `if filename.endswith(".mkv"):`
  You should also concatenate the path with the file name:

  ```
   filename = os.path.join(pathdir, filename)  # Prints: path/to/dir/fg_av_ger_seg0.mkv
  ```
- Instead of listing all the files, and look for files that ends with `.mkv`, you may filter the list from advance using `glob.glob`:

  ```
   mkv_filenames_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(pathdir, "*.mkv"))
  ```
- It's recommended to replace the `.mkv` extension with `.wav` extension (not just adding `.wav`):

  ```
   wav_file_name = filename.replace('.mkv', '.wav')
  ```
- Make sure that the MKV files are in the correct path, and that you have read permissions to the files, and write permissions to the folder.

---

Here is a complete code sample (change `pathdir`, or put the Python script at the same folder as the MKV files):

```
import moviepy
import os
import glob
import moviepy.editor 

pathdir = "."

# Get a list of all the files with .mkv extension in pathdir folder.
mkv_filenames_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(pathdir, "*.mkv"))

for filename in mkv_filenames_list:
    print(filename)
        
    video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(filename)
    audio = video.audio

    # Some of my MKV files are without audio.
    if audio is not None:
        wav_file_name = filename.replace('.mkv', '.wav')  # Replace .mkv with .wav
        audio.write_audiofile(wav_file_name)
else:
    print("Finished conversion")
```

Comment: Hello Rotem, Thank you so much for your correction! It works very well, I appreciate your time and help! All the best

Comment: Thanks, Worked for me. helped in handling video files without audio.